# Colors look different from device to simulator

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have this UIWebView that reads from an HTML file with this style:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(9,57,48) 0%, rgb(54,97,71) 0%, rgb(120,169,118) 80%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(9,57,48) 0%, rgb(54,97,71) 0%, rgb(120,169,118) 80%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(9,57,48) 0%, rgb(54,97,71) 0%, rgb(120,169,118) 80%);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(9,57,48) 0%, rgb(54,97,71) 0%, rgb(120,169,118) 80%);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(9,57,48) 0%, rgb(54,97,71) 0%, rgb(120,169,118) 80%);

        background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0, rgb(9,57,48)),
        color-stop(0, rgb(54,97,71)),
        color-stop(0.8, rgb(120,169,118))
        );
    }
</style>
```

when i'm running it on the iPhone Simulator everything goes well and it looks like that:

[image: simulator]

the problem is when i'm running it on the device, it looks like that (check the buttom of the image):

[image: device]

How can make this blurry white end to disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your white color stop to be at 100% (1.0) for your gradients.

Comment: `bottom, rgb(9,57,48) 0%, rgb(54,97,71) 0%, rgb(120,169,118) 80%` should be `bottom, rgb(9,57,48) 0%, rgb(54,97,71) 0%, rgb(120,169,118) 100%`, for example, and `color-stop(0.8, rgb(120,169,118))` should be `color-stop(1.0, rgb(120,169,118))`.